# Call a SQL function in a query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have an issue with a function in SQL Server 2008, if I execute a query with a function, it takes like 40 secs, if I remove the function and I add the logic of the function in the query, is 0 secs!

Anybody can explain me the reason of why using a function could be so slow? I really want to use the function to encapsulate the logic but I don't find the way of...

Comment: Post the code within the function.

Comment: provide some code? also type of function scalar? inline table? how is it being used whats the function doing?

Comment: Is the function called within a WHERE or JOIN clause?

Comment: There are known problems with UDFs: http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/524983/user-defined-function-performance-is-unacceptable. However, this seems excessive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of a scalar UDF in JOINs or the WHERE clause can prevent the use of indexes forcing SQL Server to do a table scan. It also will prevent SQL Server from estimating row-counts correctly which can cause bad plan choices later on. There is also the invocation cost for every row that can add up.

In general it is a good idea to stay away from scalar valued UDFs. However you can use inline table valued functions to encapsulate your logic. They are handled just like views and resolved by the optimizer. Important is that you are using the inline TVF type. Multi statement TVFs are even worse than scalar UDFs.

For more details check out my article here: [Performance Comparisons of different types of Functions](http://sqlity.net/en/498/t-sql-tuesday-24-prox-n-funx/)